# What is the meaning of "for" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I've encountered this sentence, but I can't understand what is the function of `for` in it. Also, what is the subject for `... is to understand ...`

> But it is worth trying, **for** to understand the initial shock of those images **is to understand the extraordinary power and magic of cinema**, the unique, hypnotic quality that has made film the most dynamic, effective art form of the 20th century.

Comment: Its function depends on which grammar you subscribe to: some people treat it as a subordinator in which case its function is **marker** of the subordinate clause it introduces; others (including me) treat it as a preposition, in which case its function is **head** of the preposition phrase.  Either way the meaning is similar to "because" or "as".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Erin pointed out, in this context [for](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) is a conjunction meaning **because**.

There is a 1958 song by the Teddy Bears called "to know him is to love him". This gives a clue how to read the **...is to understand...** section.

> to understand X is to understand Y

What this means is that if you get to a point where you understand X, you will be also able to understand Y.

Answer (score 0):

In this example for is being used as a conjunction like because or since.

Here is a website with some examples: [Using “For” to Mean “Because”](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/using-%E2%80%9Cfor%E2%80%9D-to-mean-%E2%80%9Cbecause%E2%80%9D)

Comment: Can you also explain what is the subject for "is to understand ..."?

Comment: @Sam the non-finite clause _is to understand ..._ is subjectless, as is typical of non-finite clauses. We understand the subject to be some arbitrary persons.

Comment: @BillJ: don't forget the **is**.  To get down and dirty, you should say that **is to understand...** is a verb + subject complement (ok, it's a verb + subjectless subject complement if you want to be pedantic), and its subject is **to understand the initial shock...**. Call that a subjectless subject if you will.

Comment: Sorry, I was being sloppy. I should have said _to understand the extraordinary..._ (not _is to understand ..._). The subject clause and the complement clause are both subjectless non-finites (though both subjects are understood as the same arbitrary persons). We understand: for x to understand y is for x to understand z.